# UTF-8 encoding from JSP to PortletRequest

Tags: encoding, utf-8

```
 In the input field of the jsp page we are giving some value with special characters Arągł but those are not coming as given in the form. The value of the String query should be same as given but it's some thing like ArÄgÅ
```

Server side code:

```
     public void sendForm(PortletRequest request, Model model) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {   
             Map<String, String[]> renderParams = request.getParameterMap();
             for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : renderParams.entrySet()) {
                final String key = entry.getKey();
              final String[] c = entry.getValue();
                if (c != null && c.length > 0) {
                   if(key.contains("query")) {
                        String query = c[0];
                   }
                }
           }
        }
```

JSP code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="portlet" uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <portlet:defineObjects />

    <portlet:actionURL var="formUrl" name="sendForm"/>

    <form name="editForm" 
          method="POST"
          action="${formUrl}"
          >
    <input type="text" name="query" id="query"/> 
        <input value="Submit" type="submit" />
    </form>
```

In the input field of the jsp page we are giving some value with special characters Arągł but those are not coming as given in the form. The value of the String query should be same as given but it's some thing like ArÄgÅ